# How do I preserve the original img src (disable Data URI) when pasting an image in a Firefox contentEditable div

Tags: firefox, image, contenteditable, paste, data-uri

I have an editor which contains a div with contentEditable=true, where I let the user paste images from the clipboard, as well as change the image's SRC attribute from inside the editor.

In IE it's working fine, but in Firefox the image is automatically serialized on paste, i.e. the src attribute becomes something like data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...

How do I force Firefox to keep the original image source?

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  If you did that, the image wouldn't render at all, since web pages can't link to file:// URIs in Gecko for security reasons.

Comment: I am not using file:// paths. The image has been put in the clipboard by using the "Copy image" function in the browser itself. It works fine in Chrome and IE, they're smart enough to link to the original image source on paste.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like something Firefox should just do.  File a bug?